# How can I on old VB6 get real temperature of CPU and GPU? Without WMI

Tags: vb6, cpu, temperature

I've only seen examples for VB.NET. But I need to do this on VB6. Does anyone have examples or can do this?
[How can I see temperature of CPU using VB.NET with Open Hardware Monitor DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774626/how-can-i-see-temperature-of-cpu-using-vb-net-with-open-hardware-monitor-dll)

Can someone edit the code from VB.NET in VB6?

I realized that there are no built-in WinAPI functions for temperature and many uses a third-party dynamic library for this - OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll . Where can I find all the functions of this library to use in VB6? In addition, the library was created in C# for .NET and 99.9% won't work on VB6! Perhaps there is another way to get the real temperature?

WMI - I don't consider it, because either it doesn't work, or it displays identical parameters

"wmic /namespace:\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get Current Temperature"

PS: I think until someone writes a ready-made library for use(With a description of the functions), so these questions will appear to many in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken. Visual Basic 6 and OHM will operate together, you just have to experiment connecting to WMI. There are many examples on the internet.

```vb
Public Sub getgblSensorArray(ByRef thisArray() As String, ByRef gblSensorCount As Integer)
    
    ' dimension all variables
    Dim strComputer As String: strComputer = vbnullstring
    Dim objSWbemLocator As Object
    Dim objSWbemServices As Object
    Dim colItems As Object
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim thisSensorCount As Integer: thisSensorCount = 0
    Dim I As Integer: I = 0
    
    On Error GoTo getGblSensorArray_Error
    
    strComputer = "."  ' localhost
    
    ' connect to WMI
    Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set objSWbemServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, "root\OpenHardwareMonitor")
    
    ' execute query on temperature sensors
    Set colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Sensor WHERE SensorType = 'Temperature'")

    ' extract the number of sensors
    thisSensorCount = colItems.Count
    
    ' create an array containing the name and values of each sensor in the system
    ReDim thisArray(thisSensorCount, 4) As String
    For Each objItem In colItems
        thisArray(I, 1) = objItem.Name
        thisArray(I, 2) = objItem.Value
        thisArray(I, 3) = objItem.Max
        thisArray(I, 4) = objItem.Identifier
        I = I + 1
    Next
          
    gblSensorCount = thisSensorCount
        
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

getGblSensorArray_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure getGblSensorArray, line " & Erl & "."

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**